# Reading a file in C if each row is terminated by a newline

Tags: c, file

Apparently I'm having some issue reading a file, line by line, or character by character, because each row of my file is terminated by a newline character. 
I think the issue is related to those newline characters because when I'm trying to read the file, using or fgetc() or fgets(), when I attempt to print the result on stdout I'm given... nothing.

Example of first file that gives me the issue:

```
12345678
12849499
47484900
```

I tried with another file, such as

```
123456596945869498
```

And the output on stdout, parsing the file using fgetc() or fgets(), is what I expect: the content of the file.

Now, the aim of the read from file is to store the content of the file in a matrix at pointers. I tried in many ways to bypass those newlines. I tried like this:

```
i = 0;
while((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF){
    if(c != '\n')
       p[i][j++] = c; /*Incrementing j by one ad each iteration */
    if(c == '\n')
        i++; /*If c == '\n', skip to the next row of the matrix */
    }
```

Where I is the row index and j is the column index.
I even tried with fgets, like this, as suggested by a member of this forum:

```
while((fgets(line, col,f))!= NULL){
        p[i++] = strdup(line);
        }
```

Can anybody help me figuring out how to solve this issue?

This is the main of the my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define K 100

int main() {
  FILE *f;

  f = fopen("out_test6_1.txt", "r");

  int row = 0;
  int col = 0;
  char c;

  // Evaluating number of rows and columns of the new matrix, 
  // parsing the file in search of newlines chars

  while((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF ) {
    if(c != '\n' && row == 0)
    col++;

    else if(c == '\n')
    row++;
  }

  printf("rows %d\n", row);
  printf("columns %d\n", col);

  int i, j;
  char**p = malloc(row*sizeof(char*));
  for(i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    p[i] = malloc(col*sizeof(char));
  }

  i = 0;
  while((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
    if(c != '\n')
    p[i][j++] = c;
    if(c == '\n')
    i++;
  }

  for(i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      printf("%c", p[i][j]);
    }
  }

  fclose(f);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post a [mcve].  Perhaps file failed to open.

Comment: Added some piece of code attempt, main of the program and some file examples.

Comment: After `f = fopen(...`, add `if (f == NULL) { puts("error"); exit(1); }`

Comment: Post the output seen such as from `printf("rows %d\n", row);`.

Comment: Key problem: the 2nd `while((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF){` should quit right away as the file has been read.  Precede that with `rewind(f);`

Comment: The output is correct. It print the right number of rows and columns of each file I try. The problem lies in the read from file and store in matrix. I added the piece regarding the check if f == NULL or not but nothing has changed.

Comment: So after both the while loop I procede with rewind(f)?

Comment: @chux `if(f==NULL) { perror("out_test6_1.txt"); exit(1); }`, but the path ought to be in a variable to avoid duplication of a hard coded string. (eg `perror(argv[1])`)

Comment: @WilliamPursell When an error occurs - it is a balance of printing out useful info like `perror(argv[1])` and defensive coding.  After all, the file failed to open so the `argv[1]` may need vetting to prevent printing from a malicious pointer.  For me, I like a clean constant error message followed by informational messages.

Comment: @chux, the point of the comment is that error messages belong on stderr rather than stdout and should contain useful information about the cause of the error.  Printing "error" to stdout is *not* "defensive coding".

Comment: @Chiara Rewinding before both`while` loops is OK.   Rewinding before the first  `while` loop  is not needed as the file was just opened.

Comment: Now my code is almost working fine. The last problem lies in the second loop. Apparently what I’m doing wrong is the way I’m incrementing the j index. I don’t understand why.

Comment: @Chiara "Now my code is almost working fine." good.  If the original posted question is solved, then this post is done.  Learn from it, research and debug remaining issues.  If still stuck post a new question - tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Code reads the file to find the rows and columns yet fails to rewind before the 2nd pass.

```
i = 0;
rewind(f);  // add
while((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
```

---

Some other problems noted:

```
// To properly distinguish all characters from EOF
// char c;
int c;
```

I'd expect code to find the maximum column width and use that later.

```
  size_t max_col = 0;
  while((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF ) {
    col++;
    if (c == '\n') {
      if (col > max_col) {
        max_col = col;
        col = 0;
      }
      row++;
    }
  }
  if (col > max_col) {
    max_col = col;
  }

  ... 
  // p[i] = malloc(col*sizeof(char));
  p[i] = malloc(sizeof *(p[i]) * max_col);
```